# Is the Elasticsearch tagline a reference to something?

Tags: elasticsearch

When you curl an elasticsearch instance it returns the tagline "You Know, for search" (amongst other things). Is this a pop-culture reference? It feels familiar but I can't quite put my finger on it. If not, is there any information on why they chose this, slightly unusual, line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-know-for-search-inc) blog for information.

Below as mentioned in blog and it seems like that is source for tagline:

> Obviously, I knew all those things, but not many others did. Its
> funny, as Tim Robbins found out in the classic Cohen brothers movie,
> “The Hudsucker Proxy", getting people to see a circle and state “You
> Know, for Kids!", and making the leap to understand what it can
> actually be is not simple.

Comment: That sums it up perfectly... thank you!